# How to call a random function

Tags: c++

Say I have a class `A` with methods `functionA()`, `functionB()` and `functionC()`:

```
class A {

int functionA () {
}

int functionB() {
}

int functionC() {
}

};
```

how would I go about calling functionA, functioB and functionC at random?

Comment: call functions in if statement could help you

Comment: You can store pointers to the methods into an array, then generate a random index and call the method at that index

Answer (score 8):

**Method 1**

One of the naive methods can be to generate a random number and call the functions based on the generated number in an `if` statements or `switch`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

int main(void) 
{
    A a;
    srand(time(0));
    int a = rand()%3;

    switch (a)
    {
    case 0:
        a.functionA();
        break;

    case 1:
        a.functionB();
        break;


    case 2:
        a.functionC();
        break;


    default:
        break;
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

**Method 2**

Based on the Comment by @Remy Lebeau, I recommend the following approach

```
int main(void) 
{ 
    srand(time(0));

    int (A::*arr[])() = {&A::functionA, &A::functionB, &A:functionC};

/* 
   **Note**
   You need to call the non-static class methods using an Object of the 
   class. So we make an object and call methods using that object.
*/

    A a;

    (a.*arr[rand() % 3])();

    return 0; 
}
```

**Edit**

As suggested by @cdihowie, c/c++ random library is not recommended as the random number generated may not be uniform. We can use uniform_distribution for generating uniform pseudo random numbers. So your final code becomes as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    int functionA()
    {
        printf("inside functionA()\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int functionB()
    {
        printf("inside functionB()\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int functionC()
    {
        printf("inside functionC()\n");
        return 0;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::default_random_engine generator(seed);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 2);

    A a;
    A *aPtr = new A();

    int (A::*arr[])() = {&A::functionA, &A::functionB, &A::functionC};

    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    {
        int num = distribution(generator);
        (a.*arr[num])();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the distribution of selected functions may not be uniform using `std::rand()`.  Consider using [the C++11 random API](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random).

Comment: Thanks for the commend @cdhowie, i will update it in the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `rand()` function to randomize it as follows.

```c
A a;
int randFuncIdx = std::rand() % 3;
switch(randFuncIdx) {
  case 0:
    a.functionA();
    break;
  case 1:
    a.functionB();
    break;
  case 2:
    a.functionC();
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```